# Execute statements only after the Jquery promise is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I was trying to execute a function which need to execute statements sequentially.
I used Jquery deferred for promises, but the statements after the promise execute initially. How can I execute all statements sequentially?
http://jsfiddle.net/e4wptvjv/

```
var test = 0;
function a(){
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function(){    
    console.log("a completed");
    test++;
    deferred.resolve("from a");
  },500);
  return deferred.promise();
};
function b(){
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("b completed");
    test++;
    deferred.resolve("from b");
  },200);
  return deferred.promise();
}

function testFn(){
  var d = jQuery.Deferred(), 
  p=d.promise();
  p.then(a).then(b);
  d.resolve();
  console.log("this statement will execute after a & b completed");
  return test;
}

var result = testFn();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: the code suffers a common misconception, that asynchronous code can be made synchronous by using Promise. There is no way to make asynchronous code synchronous, and if you stop to think about it, it's quite obvious

Comment: Rebornx, you already understand `p.then(a).then(b)` so it's not a massive step to understand `p.then(a).then(b).then(doSomethingElse)`.

Comment: @JaromandaX Now I got the point.

Answer (score 1):

I update you code

http://jsfiddle.net/e4wptvjv/3/

this is the code of the testFn function

```
return a().then(b).then(function(){console.log("this statement will execute after a & b completed");return "last"});;
```

I call a function first, at the end I call b function and then I put into the console the message and return a string.

Comment: But I cannot call the initial function as you suggested. testFn().then(function(lastResult){
console.log(lastResult);
}); it must be called as result = testFn();

Comment: you can't direcly have a result from testFn. In every case it will be a promise because of promise are asynchronous

Comment: So you mean there is no way to achieve synchronous execution behavior? or forcing promise to complete for execute next statement?

Comment: No, you can't. But i make a question to you: why use promises if  you want a sync execution?

Comment: Bcz there is few ajax requests in both functions.

Comment: If you use jquery ajax you can make your http calls sync by setting async property to false, but i Think that it is not the best choice, because if you do multiple calls your browser will be blocked until they end

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dyh1jgLj/3/

Unlike Marco Morelli Moretti's answer, this one does 'a' and 'b' parallel, but waits for them both.

```
function testFn(){
  $.when(a(), b()).then(function(){
    console.log("this statement will execute after a & b completed");
  });
}
```

Comment: Still the final result is undefined :( Bcz that statement execute before those  promise got completed

Comment: @Rebornx you're asking for the impossible. JavaScript is **synchronous**, and if you look at your code, there part where you assign `result` is not handling the asynchronous behaviour of `testFn()`. If all of your code is wrapped in a function, just make use of the promises as both of the answers have hinted at, and then let the wrapping function return the promise.